# Contraction Maping Example

Tags: functional-analysis

Can we find a function f from a norm space E to E that is not a contraction mapping but $f\circ f$ is a contraction mapping ?

Can anyone help me with this problem ? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to look at a 2-dimensional real vector space with the 2-Norm:
just take the linear Map.

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
0.25 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

the norm of $A$ is $2$, but the norm of $A^2$ is $0.5$

Comment: do you have any counter-example of a function on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}-2\,x & x\le0,\\
0 & x>0\end{cases}.$$
Then $f\circ f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much professor. Can I ask you 1 more question: How did you come up with this answer ?

Comment: Years of experience. I looked for a function constant on a region $D$  (in this case $D=(0,\infty)$) and mapping the complement of $D$ to $D$, so that the composition is constant.